# Number of TCP connections for a "bidirectional" topic?

Tags: ros, tcpros, topic, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a (possibly) simple question: assume if I have two nodes A, B that communicate over a topic "/my_topic", i.e., *both* nodes subscribe and publish to "/my_topic" using TCPROS. How many TCP connections are being created for this? (I am asking because I am concerned with race conditions in my parallel system of many ROS nodes, most probably due to messages being sent to a topic but the intended receiver(s) is/are not already connected.)

According to the [ROS 1: Technical Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview), I would assume that there are **two TCP connections**, one for the publisher on node A and one for B (although and unfortunately, one would be enough).

In other words: in theory, it would be sufficient to just have ONE TCP connection which is used in both directions. In that the case here?

Is that correct?

Thank you so much! :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335235/number-of-tcp-connections-for-a-%22bidirectional%22-topic?/) by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2019-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1)

> both nodes subscribe and publish to
> "/my_topic" using TCPROS.

don't do that. You're not going to know what came from who unless you encoded it in the message, but either way there's going to be alot (50%) of waste both nodes have to deal with. Triggering callbacks to decode wasteful messages isn't "free". Just use 2 topics /my_topic/A & /my_topic/B or something.

2)
Yes, there are 2, each connection will get one. Without g oing deeper into the ros comms layers, I don't believe that is possible (or even if you did).

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2019-10-15**:
Thanks for clarifying! Unfortunately, I need a single topic in my case and in fact, there are many more robots subscribing and publishing to that single topic (because I require that every robot communicates with every other robot (O(n²)) and I see no other way of achieving this (except for using a topic). Do you?